# Every bounded sequence converges

Tags: sequences-and-series

Q) Prove or disprove : Every bounded sequence converges. (Make sure
to fully justify your answer. That is provide a proof if true otherwise
provide a counterexample and justify why your counterexample satisfy
the desired criteria.

## Solution

My counter example is $a_n = (-1)^n $, I know I could just leave it as this but I want to prove that this diverges but I've never worked with a proof like that so could someone check it?

Firstly: {-1,1,-1,...} Therefore the sequence is bounded above by 1 and bounded below by -1. Therefore this sequence is bounded.

Proof that this sequence diverges:

Assuming the contradiction that $\{a_n\}$ converges.

WTS: $\exists L \in \mathbb R, \forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N > 0$, such that for all $n \in \mathbb N$, if $n > N$, then $|(-1)^n - L| < \epsilon$

Let $\epsilon = 1$

n is odd: if $n > N$, then $$|L+1| < 1$$

$$ \Leftrightarrow -2 < L < 0$$

n is even: if $n > N$, then $$|L-1| < 1$$

$$\Leftrightarrow 0 < L < 2$$

Thus $L \in (-2,0)$ and $L \in (0,2)$. Therefore this is a contradiction and $(-1)^n$ diverges. Therefore not all bounded sequences converge.

If this is correct I dont get why this actually proves it diverges, mainly this part: "$L \in (-2,0)$ and $L \in (0,2)$."

Could someone explain that? I was looking at a similar proof when writing this.

EDIT: Not a duplicate because I'm asking my additional proof is correct.

Comment: $L$ is one single quantity. The point is, the above proof tries to show that it belongs in both of the two ranges $(-2,0)$ and $(0,2)$, which cannot happen as they are disjoint ranges, so $L$ can't be in both of them.

Comment: You are welcome. If you wanted to make things clearer, just take $\epsilon = 0.01$ or something, and it will become even clearer.

Comment: I asked if my divergence proof is correct. That isn't a duplicate because that only shows the counter example.

Comment: @Tinler:  You did ask if "your" divergence proof is correct, but you then expressed doubt as to why $L\in (-2,0)$ and at the same time $L\in (0,2)$ "is a contradiction".  So part of the proof is coming up with the counterexample, which is shared by the duplicate.  I suspect a moments reflection will satisfy you that no limit $L$ can belong to both of the intervals you describe.  I've rolled back your edit, which rendered the problem statement unreadable.  If you wish to delete your Question, despite having received and accepted an Answer, you can flag the Question for moderator action.

Comment: Its all good. DW

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yet another**:

For any $L$,

$$\max(|L-1|,|L+1|)\ge1$$ so that you can't ensure $|L-(-1)^n|<\epsilon$.

Answer (score 2):

Another proof: assume that $(a_n)$ converges. Then $|a_{n+1}-a_n| \to 0$. But we have:  $|a_{n+1}-a_n| =2$ for all $n$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need *assume* something that *you know is wrong* and then expose a contradiction. Just recall the definition and show its prerequisities can't be satisfied.

The convergence is equivalent to, and in fact is defined by, the existence of a limit:

> for a sequence, if (actually: iff) there exists a number $L$ which satisfies
>
> > for arbitrarily small margin allowed, almost all terms of the sequence get at least *that close* to $L$,
>
> then we call $L$ a limit of the sequence, and we call the sequence 'convergent'.

Thus it's sufficient to show no candidate satisfies the requirements for a limit:

- for any $L\ne 1$ there exsist infinitely many terms equal $1$, that is $|L-1|$ apart from $L$, thus not arbitrarily close to $L$;
- and for $L=1$ there are infinitely many terms equal $-1$, thus not arbitrarily close to $L$,

to conclude: no candidate $L\in\mathbb R$ satisfies the definition's requirements, hence there is no limit, and the sequence is not convergent.
With no contradiction.

The same said @Yves Daoust before, and got the [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2196295/152299) accepted, so this may be considered as duplicating the answer – but I wanted to show that basic mathematics can be done and explained without much formalism.